# Installing Xampp on MS Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2003, xampp

I have a Windows Server 2003 and asp.net website running on localhost. I have to install php and mysql, but php installation doesn't work for whatever reason. I was wondering if I could install package such as xampp on windows server to save time and hassle installing in manually (I could not find a tutorial for this). I was wondering though, if it is safe, i.e. what will happen if I go to http://localhost/ - will I get the php or asp website? In general, is it safe to install xampp on windows server 2003? All advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's safe to install both.  What you do is bind one to one port and the other to another port, so IIS is port 80 and Apache is port 81 or whatever, http://localhost/ would go to IIS and http://localhost:81/ would go to apache.

Comment: How to bind it? I've installed xampp, but I guess php is not working. I do not know how to test it cause I cannot go to localhost since there is asp installed...

Comment: You would modify the httpd.conf file to change the Listen port, and restart Apache to make the changes take effect. 81 or 8080 are usually pretty good options.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft got a detailed oficial instructionpage for PHP on IIS under h**p://php.iis.net/

You probably got IIS 6 running on that Windows 2003 Server. The following article describes how to run PHP apps

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/247/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-60/

If you have no experience with XAMPP or Apache Webserver I wouldn't recommend to install it... especially on a production system.